# its my research project i need to develop finger print scanner for android

Tags: java, android

I need to develop finger print scanner for android in which we can save our thumb prints and later on use them to verify different users but i  cant find how to take fingerprints and save them in data base its my research project please help me.
If there is any source code or any other helping material.

Answer (score 2):

> i cant find how to take fingerprints and save them in data

If the device has a fingerprint scanner in hardware, and it is running Android 6.0, you can use fingerprint APIs to validate a fingerprint. You cannot actually get the fingerprint scan yourself, for privacy and security reasons.

If the device has a fingerprint scanner in hardware, and it is running an older version of Android, you will need to contact the device manufacturer. They may have some sort of API for the fingerprint scanner, or they may not.

Otherwise, you will need to find some hardware fingerprint scanner manufacturer, one that has a scanner that supports Android and connects via USB, Bluetooth, etc. You will need to find out from that manufacturer what the API is and what it can do.

Comment: That's not right technically, he can always take a front facing picture and attempt to use visual recognition software. I did this back when Android was starting. But i don't feel like doing the work for him.

Comment: @codeCompiler77: "That's not right technically, he can always take a front facing picture and attempt to use visual recognition software" -- you have a lot more faith in the power of low-end Android cameras than I do. There is still a small percentage of devices that don't even *have* a front-facing camera, let alone a decent one. And that's on top of the complexities of the image recognition bits.

Comment: that's how we did it when android was first starting out, we had terrible front facing camera's. QR codes were just starting out. It's kind of unrealistic of his prof to expect him to have a fingerprint scanner unless he chose the project himself. Which would be funny if he doesn't have it :D